# update table in mysql get strange results

Tags: php, mysql

I try to update an existing table in mysql, but I get strange results, I explain my problem:

My table looks like this:

```
TABLE `myTable` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`photoName` varchar(255) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`vote` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `photoName_2` (`photoName`),
)
```

and im trying to use saveVote.php that look like this:

```
$namePhoto = $_POST['name']; 
$likePhoto = $_POST['like']; 

mysql_connect("host","dbUser","psw");

mysql_select_db("db_is");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `myTable` (`photoName`,`vote`) VALUES('$namePhoto','$likePhoto') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE vote = vote + 1");
```

the 'vote' value is updated but every time when i call the "saveVote.php", for the first time he create an empty entry in my table with only the `vote` value and after, each time  the "saveVote.php" is called 
the `vote` value is updated for the right `photoName` but the `vote` value for the empty entry is also updated.

Why my request created this empty entry ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: please share the code that sends `POST` data to `saveVote.php`

Comment: I m sending POST data from an iOS app saveVote.php, you can show this http://bytes.com/topic/php/insights/664241-using-html-forms-pass-data-php for sending from html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your $namePhoto = $_POST['name']; is also returning a empty value. Try this:

```
if(!empty($_POST['name'])){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `myTable` (`photoName`,`vote`) VALUES('$namePhoto','$likePhoto') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE vote = vote + 1");
}
```

Keep in mind that this is just to test. This is not a fix. You need to figure out why you are sending a empty value.

Comment: thanks for help but when i add your code the table isn't updated

Comment: sorry i had a syntax error. Missed a ) at the if statement

Comment: Big thanks, It work great with the if statement for the $_POST['name'] empty value  , i think that the empty data is send by the ios Code but i m not at home and i can't verify my Objc-C code..

Comment: Glad to hear that. I recommend using a webdeveloper tool like Firebug to see what kind of posts you are making. Now we know that your php code is working so it has something to do with your form submission.

Comment: I do not usually use PHP and I did not know Firebug I'll watch all this , thank you again;)